# Jasmine unit testing angular service that returns promise doesn't resolve

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Given this Test Code

```
it('can login', inject(function ($httpBackend,$rootScope) {
        // Set up the mock http service responses
        authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('POST', '/login')
            .respond({success: true, user: {email: 'david@blah.com', roles: ['user']}});
        var promise = dsAuth.authenticateUser('123', '123')

        promise.then(function (success) {
            console.log('Got login response');
            expect(success).toBe(true);
            expect(dsIdentity.isAuthenticated()).toBe(true);
            console.log(dsIdentity.currentUser);
        });
        $rootScope.$digest(); //a solution found in on SO that doesn't work
    }));
```

That promise (which gets returned from the auth service) never resolves? How can this be fixed ?  the code in the .then() function is never called

Service Code :

```
(function(angular) {
angular.module('dsApp').factory('dsAuth',
    ['$http','$q',dsAuth]);
function dsAuth($http,$q) {
    return {
        authenticateUser: function(username,password) {
            var dfd = $q.defer();
            $http.post('/login', {username: username, password: password}).then(function (resp) {
                console.log($resp);
                if (resp.data.success) {
                    var user = new atUser();
                    angular.extend(user, resp.data.user);
                    atIdentity.currentUser = user;
                    dfd.resolve(true);
                } else {
                    dfd.resolve(false);
                }
            });
            return dfd.promise;
        },
        logoutUser: function() {
            var dfd = $q.defer();
            $http.post('/logout', {logout: true}).then(function () {
                atIdentity.currentUser = undefined;
                dfd.resolve();
            });
            return dfd.promise;
        }
    };
}
```

})(this.angular);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasmine doesn't work with asynchronous expects. The solution to this is to use the `flush()` function of `httpBackend`.

```
it('can login', inject(function ($httpBackend,$rootScope) {
        // Set up the mock http service responses
        authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('POST', '/login')
            .respond({success: true, user: {email: 'david@blah.com', roles: ['user']}});
        var promise = dsAuth.authenticateUser('123', '123')
        var success = false;

        promise.then(function (result) {
            console.log('Got login response');
            success = result;
            console.log(dsIdentity.currentUser);
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(success).toBe(true);
        expect(dsIdentity.isAuthenticated()).toBe(true);
    }));
```

I'm not really sure where the `dsIdentity` comes from, but I presume you can figure that out in your own code. The pattern is the same - create a variable  outside the closure and then set the value inside the closure. The `flush()` will cause the promise to fire and then you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks a bunch didn't realize it wasn't async compatible